# perl Test::MockModule with DB acces

Tags: perl, unit-testing, oop, mocking, moo

I'm starting in the unit testing world in Perl. Here is my question: I have a class in Perl (I'm using Moo BTW) and this class has 3 attributes (I'm going to put the code bellow). One of these attributes is an array, and it is generated automatically in the constructor. To generate the array, I need to access to a DB and execute one query.

```
package Customer;
use 5.010;
use Data::Dumper;
use Moo;
use TT::SQL;

has id => (
  is=>'ro',
  required=>1,
);

has type => (
  is=>'ro',
);

has emails => (
  is=>'rw',
  default => sub {
     my ($self) = @_;
     return $self->getEmails();
  },
  lazy=> 1,
);

sub getEmails
{               
                my $self=shift;
                #obtaining the DB handler
                my $db2 = $self->get_db_handler();
                my $fmuser=$self->id;
                my $type=$self->type;
                my $query;
                #checking the customer type to perform the query
                if ($type eq "tshop")
                {
                $query="SELECT email from XXXXXXX WHERE XXXXX=? and XXXXXXXX=1 and XXXXXXX =1'";
                }
                else
                {
                $query="SELECT email from XXXXXXXX WHERE XXXXX=? and XXXXXXXX=1 and XXXXXXX =1";
                }
                my $ref = $db2->execute($query,$fmuser);
                my @emails;
                #retrieving emails
                while ( my $row = $ref->fetchrow_hashref  ) {
                       @emails=(@emails,"$row->{email}\n");
                  }
                return \@emails;
}

sub get_db_handler
{
        my $user = "XXXXXXX";
    my $password = 'XXXXXXX';
    my $host = "XXXXX";
    my $driver = "Pg";
    my $timezone = "America/New_York";

    my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:database=fm;host=$host";
    my $db = DBI->connect($dsn,$user,$password) or die("Cannot connect to the DB !!");
    return $db;

}

1;
```

Now I want to run unit tests to check the behavior of the previous class. Until now, i'm using Test::MockModule as next:

```
use diagnostics; # this gives you more debugging information
use warnings;    # this warns you of bad practices
use strict;      # this prevents silly errors
use Moo;
use Data::Dumper;
use Test::More tests => 2; # for the is() and isnt() functions
use Customer;
use FindBin qw/$RealBin/;
use Test::Deep;
use Test::MockModule;
use DBI;
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=$RealBin/test-cutomer.db","","") or die $DBI::errstr;
$dbh->do("
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    field1 INTEGER,
    field2 INTEGER,
    field3 TEXT,
    field4 INTEGER,
    field5 INTEGER
)
");

$dbh->do('
        INSERT INTO table (field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) VALUES 
        (?,?,?,?,?)',undef,undef,92,'XXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXXX',1,1
);

END {
    unlink "$RealBin/test-customer.db";
}

{

my $mock = Test::MockModule->new("Customer");
$mock->mock("get_db_handler", sub { return $dbh });

my $customer=Customer->new(id=>92,type=>'other');

ok(defined $customer);
my $e=$customer->emails;
my @emails=@$e;
my $length=@emails;
is($length,1, 'the emails are OK');
}
```

I want to mock the get_db_handler method to retrieve the test-customer.db  handler and to run the queries over this local DB.
So far, I'm getting the following error:

```
1..2
ok 1
Can't locate object method "execute" via package "DBI::db" at Customer.pm line
    46 (#1)
    (F) You called a method correctly, and it correctly indicated a package
    functioning as a class, but that package doesn't define that particular
    method, nor does any of its base classes.  See perlobj.

Uncaught exception from user code:
    Can't locate object method "execute" via package "DBI::db" at Customer.pm line 46.
 at Customer.pm line 46
    Customer::getEmails('Customer=HASH(0x11359c8)') called at Customer.pm line 23
    Customer::__ANON__('Customer=HASH(0x11359c8)') called at (eval 23) line 18
    Customer::emails('Customer=HASH(0x11359c8)') called at t/stc.t line 66
# Looks like you planned 2 tests but ran 1.
# Looks like your test exited with 2 just after 1.
```

The script is running OK, I mean, there is no problem with the code. The problem is with the **test**. Could you please take a look at this? I'll appreciate it a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I'm working in the example. But, can you explain a little bit more about your first comment?

Comment: If I don't have to choose, both! hahahaha It will be awesome for me if you can provide me an example of using Test:MockModule but in this way, I mean mocking an object that access to the DB in the constructor. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You can post to [codereview.se] if you want a full analysis. But for now, if you want the Customer to get stuff from some database, I'd make the `$dbh` a property with `has`. That way you can simply pass it a different `$dbh` in your tests and don't need to care about mocking. If you have several classes that need a dbh, turn it into a Moo::Role. But pay attention that sqlite might not support all features of Postgres, so there are some pitfalls with the whole sqlite approach. It's probably safer to use DBIx::Class and let it worry about that stuff.

Comment: What are you seeing wrong? or as a bad practice? Please let me know your opinion!! Thanks.

Comment: I don't have the reputation! What else can I do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109935/discussion-between-ccalderon911217-and-simbabque).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting that error is that your production code is calling `execute` on the *database handle*, and not on a *statement handle*. You have to `prepare` the query before you can `execute` it.

```
my $sth = $db2->prepare($query);
my $ref = $sth->execute($fmuser);
```

Using conventional names like `$dbh`, `$sth` and `$res` for your DBI variables would have helped to spot that easier.

---

Test::MockModule is not the right tool for what you are doing. It's useful if you want to mock dependencies in other modules, or possibly only parts of those.

But right now you have an internal dependency. What you want to do is *dependency injection*, but your code is not prepared for that, so you need to find a different way.

I would recommend using [Sub::Override](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sub::Override) for this job. It's fairly simple. It overrides a sub in a lexical scope. That's all you really need here.

```
use Sub::Override;

my $sub = Sub::Override->new('frobnicate' => sub { return 'foo' });
```

So if you use that, your code would look something like the following. Note that I cleaned up some lines into one for the second test-case.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More;
use Sub::Override;    # this line is new

use DBI;
use FindBin qw/$RealBin/;

#                                                          typo here
my $dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:SQLite:dbname=$RealBin/test-customer.db", "", "" )
    or die $DBI::errstr;
$dbh->do(<<'EOSQL');
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    field1 INTEGER,
    field2 INTEGER,
    field3 TEXT,
    field4 INTEGER,
    field5 INTEGER
)
EOSQL

$dbh->do(<<'EOSQL');
        INSERT INTO table (field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) VALUES
        (?,?,?,?,?), undef, undef, 92, 'XXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXXX', 1, 1 );
EOSQL

{
    # this makes $customer->get_db_handler temporarily return 
    # our $dbh from outside
    my $sub = Sub::Override->new( 'Customer::get_db_handler' => sub {
        return $dbh 
    });

    my $customer = Customer->new( id => 92, type => 'other' );

    # this test-case is pretty useless        
    ok defined $customer, 'Customer is defined';    

    is scalar @{ $customer->emails }, 1, 
        '... and the emails were fetched form the DB';
}

END {
    unlink "$RealBin/test-customer.db";
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error as the beginning...
Can't locate object method "execute" via package "DBI::db".

Comment: No worries! Thank you very much!

Comment: Where should I put it? I'm pretty sure that's the error! Wow man you're great!

Comment: Yes yes, the code is working. I just run it and it returns the expected values.

Comment: You're right, the thing is that I'm using a handler who does have the execute method. Trying to fix it... I'll let you know.

Comment: Thank you very much man! I forgot about the handler! Now is working with Sub::Override! I'm gonna test it later with Test::MockModule. Which one would you recommend?

Comment: @cc I would go with Sub::Override in this scenario because it has the lighter footprint and is easier to use. For a single sub, I would always pick Sub::Override.

Comment: @simbabque: Please would you tidy this comment thread? I got to flagging the fourth as *obsolete* and tired of it